# Global Temporary table rollback source

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Consider a scenario, where a global temporary table is created as “on commit preserve rows” wherein 3 rows are inserted; committed the changes; deleted a row and performed rollback, where does the rollback information come from?

Comment: Rollback information always comes from the UNDO tablespace (in think in 12c you can actually put the undo for temp tables into the temp tablespace but it's still the change vectors that were recorded during DML)

Comment: my 2 cents... as @a_horse_with_no_name said, they are stored in UNDO, but the segments are made such that each GTT has their own temporary segment and they do not know of the others segment (space allocated), they only see THEIR segment and they all get vaporised at the end of the session. So same user can have different sessions and different GTT's with easch one of them stores the value in temp segment in the UNDO

Answer (score 0):

One of the benefits of temporary tables is that `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE` statements do not generate **REDO** logs for the data changes. However, **UNDO logs for the data and REDO logs for the UNDO logs are generated**.

The information required for performing rollbacks comes from the UNDO logs and so will be in the **regular UNDO tablespace**.

Oracle Database 12c (release 12.1) introduced "Temporary UNDO", which allows the rollback information to be stored in the temporary tablespace instead of the UNDO tablespace. Some more information on temporary UNDO is available at:

http://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/temporary-undo-12cr1.php